# Poller stops working after 1 cycle

Tags: spring-integration

At the beginning of my flow I have a file inbound adapter which reads a directory periodically:

```
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filteredFiles"
    directory="${controller.cycle.lists.input.dir}"
    channel="semaphoreChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="3000"/>**  
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

When the SI workflow ends it never happens again. It seems the poller is dead and stops working.

There aren't any error messages in the log nor any warnings.

Channel configuration:

```
<int:channel id="semaphoreChannel" datatype="java.io.File"/>
```

Second configuration:

```
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filteredFiles"
    directory="${controller.cycle.lists.input.dir}"
    channel="semaphoreChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml">
    <int:poller cron="0 * * * * *" />   
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the values by hand instead of the variables? And is the value in fixed-delay in milliseconds? If so, can you try  setting this attribute `time-unit="MILLISECONDS"` just to check (this is by default actually)? And can you show us your channel?

Comment: Hi,

I modified the configuration to this one:

  <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filteredFiles"
   directory="${controller.cycle.lists.input.dir}"
   channel="semaphoreChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml">
     <int:poller fixed-rate="3000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"/> 
 </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

But the result is the same.

Comment: Can you try using a cron-trigger instead of the interval-trigger? Here is some documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/channel-adapter.html and here some cron expressions: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc1x/05.+CRON+Expressions+in+Detail?showComments=false

Comment: It has been changed to cron but result remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make sense.

Since you use default settings for other `<poller>` options, you end up with:

```
public static final int MAX_MESSAGES_UNBOUNDED = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

private volatile long maxMessagesPerPoll = MAX_MESSAGES_UNBOUNDED;
```

That means the `FileReadingMessageSource` reads **all** files by provided pattern during the single poller cycle.

The `poller` doesn't stop to work, but there is nothing more in the directory to read.

Change to this `max-messages-per-poll="1"` and let us know how it is.

From other side you can switch on DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and there will be a message in logs:

> Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'

Comment: If I'm not wrong channel adapter remembers the read file name and later it does not read the message(file) with that name again. So if you have a file named: "ABC" and this file is processed by the adapter there is no chance to process the same file again.There a special needs when you have to make the same file executed again. When az error occured in your system you have to "replay" the original file. In SI you have to shut down the entire system to  replay the same file again.
Are there any workaround to replay the original file without restarting the whole system?

Comment: Yeah... it is separete question. Feel free to raise it too. Here we should close your issue with `poller`. You should accept or not the fact that `poller` works correctly or not. The `duplicate file` issue we can consider in the separete thread.

Comment: So summarizing the problem....The problem was that I want to "replay" the same file since one of my workflow element removed the  file from that polled directory and later I wanted to put back the same file and recognized that the same file is not read by SI again. That's why I thought that the poller does not work